# Confused about the scikit-learn RMSE

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to evaluate my model and I have set the scoring to be `neg_root_mean_squared_error` the results are negative as expected ([see here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.mean_squared_error.html#sklearn.metrics.mean_squared_error)). Yet, I am used to a positive value for the RMSE (the lower the better), so is it correct if I say the RMSE of the model is +0.0725, or am I missing something?

```
crossvalidation_Decision_Trees = KFold(n_splits=4, random_state=0,shuffle=True) 
model2 = new_model.fit(X_normalized, y_for_normalized)
scores_D_Trees = cross_val_score(model2, X_normalized,y_for_normalized, scoring='neg_root_mean_squared_error', cv=crossvalidation_Decision_Trees,
 n_jobs=1)
    
    
print("\n\nDecision Trees"+": RMSE for every fold: " + str(scores_D_Trees))
print('\033[1m'+"Decision Trees"+'\033[1m'+": Average RMSE for all the folds: " + str(np.mean(scores_D_Trees)) + '\033[0m'+ ", STD: " + str(np.std(scores_D_Trees)))
```

Results:

```
Decision Trees: RMSE for every fold: [-0.0413202  -0.08435709 -0.08474064 -0.07967769]
Decision Trees: Average RMSE for all the folds: -0.07252390274931717, STD: 0.01812540303759248
```

Comment: What is `neg_root_mean_squared_error `? I'm not familiar with this metric. How is it calculated?

Comment: According to scikit-learn documentation: "For the most common use cases, you can designate a scorer object with the scoring parameter; the table below shows all possible values. All scorer objects follow the convention that higher return values are better than lower return values. Thus metrics which measure the distance between the model and the data, like metrics.mean_squared_error, are available as neg_mean_squared_error which return the negated value of the metric." I am just looking for a confirmation from a member that neg_root_mean_squared_error is simply -1 * root_mean_squared_error

Comment: Where in the documentation you're quoting from? Can you provide a link? If you are unsure why not just use an MSE? Why do you say in your post the *"results are negative as expected"*? Why do you expect negative results if you don't know how it's calculated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sklearn model selection routines, the greater the score is, the better. For MSE and similar metrics it's the other way round, so those are used with a negative sign.

Standard scorers utilize `make_scorer()` (see `sklearn/metrics/_scorer.py`):

```
neg_root_mean_squared_error_scorer = make_scorer(
    mean_squared_error, greater_is_better=False, squared=False
)
...
sign = 1 if greater_is_better else -1
...
return self._sign * self._score_func
```

So yeah, nothing but multiplying the result of `mean_squared_error(squared=False)` by `-1` happens there.

Comment: I appreciate your simple yet to the point answer. Thank you.